# NodeJS EventEmitter : use event name as "*"(asterisk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I'm trying to understand some snippet of code from one open-source project where I don't understand what means to call `EventEmitter.emit` with the asterisk `'*'` as an event name.

In some libs (like JQuery), `'*'` as an event name means 'all events'.

What does it mean within the context of the EventEmitter?

I tried to find a listener for the `'*'` event in this project, but no luck.

```
class BlaBla extends EventEmitter {

    methodCall(event){
        this.emit("*", {event}); // <- what does this mean ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the project?

Comment: @nem035 - thank's for you help! Project link - github.com/liangzeng/cqrs

Answer (score 0):

`this.emit("*", {event});` means that Calling the emit() method will execute all the functions that are registered with the on method.

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L136) and running it in the REPL shows that that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `'*'` as an event name has no special effects, it behaves as a normal event.

You can take a look at the [event emitter code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L136) and see that the only special event names are:

- ['error'](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/367065be4be33dac6e0c325f88dfa1fac1314903/doc/api/events.md#error-events) - emitted when an error occurs
- ['newListener'](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/367065be4be33dac6e0c325f88dfa1fac1314903/doc/api/events.md#event-newlistener) - emitted when new listeners are added
- ['removeListener'](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/367065be4be33dac6e0c325f88dfa1fac1314903/doc/api/events.md#event-removelistener) - emitted when existing listeners are removed

Example ([repl.it code](https://repl.it/Ew5i/0))

```
const {
  EventEmitter
} = require('events');

class BlaBla extends EventEmitter {

  methodCall(stuff) {
    this.emit("*", {
      stuff // <-- this gets passed as an argument to the handler for the '*' event
    });
  }
}

const b = new BlaBla();

b.on('a', (...args) => console.log('nope', ...args)); // <-- this doesn't run
b.on('b', (...args) => console.log('nope', ...args)); // <-- this doesn't run
b.on('*', (...args) => console.log('this gets called', ...args)); // <-- This runs

b.methodCall('this gets passed down');
```

Output

```
this gets called { stuff: 'this gets passed down' }
```

---

If in this particular project all event handlers get called when `this.emit('*')` is called, they are probably doing this manually.

Here's a simplified example of how it can be done:

```
const eventNames = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

this.on('*', () =>
  eventNames.forEach(event => this.emit(event))
);
```